# Can someone marry with daughter of brother of sister's husband

Tags: halal-haram, nikah

I want to know that is it permissible or halal in Islam to marry with a daughter of brother of sister's husband . There is situation with me something like that . I like that girl so much because of her pious and modest nature.  can I take her in my nikah according to sariya law . Please give the best advise.

Comment: There is no reason for this to be haram, so it is halal.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah It's Halal, because You are **نامحرم** for her.

Comment: This is a very poor answer (See [answer]).